# Configuring a custom event log for log4net

Tags: c#, .net, log4net, event-log

I'm using log4net for logging (duh!). Using the EventLogAppender, I can configure my application name, so that my events will show up in the Application/"My Application Name" event log. However, I'd like to log events to "Some other event log"/"My Application Name". How do I configure that?

Current config:

```xml
<appender name="EventLogAppender" type="log4net.Appender.EventLogAppender" >
    <applicationName value="My application Name" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```

For an EventLogInstaller, the code would look like this:

```
eventLogInstaller.Log = "Some other event log"; // Default "Application"
eventLogInstaller.Source = "My application name";
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You control this with the [LogName property](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.EventLogAppender.LogName.html).

E.g.:

```xml
<appender name="EventLogAppender" type="log4net.Appender.EventLogAppender" >
      <logName value="System" />
      <applicationName value="My application Name" />
      ...
</appender>
```

Comment: I have done this and it did create the new log under the Event Viewer's `Applications and Services Logs` node, but the messages are still being logged to the `Application` log for some reason instead of the new one.

Comment: Nevermind, turns out I had to restart my computer for the change to take effect, as mentioned at http://stackoverflow.com/a/6457005/602585 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7607441/log4net-eventlogappender-is-ignoring-my-logname