# Log4Net EventLogAppender Not Logging To Custom Event Log

Tags: .net, log4net, xmlconfigurator

Added an EventLogAppender as follows:

```
<appender name="eventLogAppender" type="log4net.Appender.EventLogAppender,log4net" >
    <mapping>
        <level value="ERROR" />
        <eventLogEntryType value="Error" />
    </mapping>
    <mapping>
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <eventLogEntryType value="Information" />
    </mapping>
    <mapping>
        <level value="INFO" />
        <eventLogEntryType value="Information" />
    </mapping>
    <mapping>
        <level value="WARN" />
        <eventLogEntryType value="Warning" />
    </mapping>
    <logName value="NewLogName" />
    <applicationName value="AppName" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout,log4net">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```

It creates the new log of `NewLogName` and it adds windows events with the app name of `AppName` but it adds the events to the `Application` log instead of `NewLogName`.

I've changed permissions in the registry and the Application Name is in the correct spot in the registry.  Any ideas?

Comment: And the debug output from log4net doesn't complain about anything (Add `<log4net debug="true">`)? Because tons of other Q&As about this same thing say that you're _configuring_ it correctly (permissions are another question).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Configuring a custom event log for log4net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416800/configuring-a-custom-event-log-for-log4net)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After enabling log4net internal debugging, I didn't see any errors. It created the `NewLogName` in the Event Viewer. There is no duplicate. I restarted the Event Collector and the Event Log services and it didn't fix it. I rebooted my computer last night and it looks like that fixed it.

Comment: Any clues how to achieve this without rebooting?